# Django - While registering, registered data are not saved on database and so can't perform LogIn

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication, django-auth-models, django-userena

I have been trying so hard to make an user registration and login using Django. I am using AbstractUser for this. Whenever, I enter the form fields, and click Signup the page is not getting redirected and the entered data aren't saved on the database

This is my view.py

```
    def register(request):

        if request.method == "POST":
            print("method is post")
            form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                print("form is valid")
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
                messages.success(request, f"hey {username}, account created successfully")
                new_user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                    password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])
                login(request, new_user)
                return redirect("jew_app:home")
            else:
                print(form.errors)
        else:
            print("user can't be registered")

        form = UserRegisterForm()

        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, 'user/register.html',  context)


    def user_login(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            messages.warning(request, f"Hey you are already logged in")
            return redirect("accounts:profile")

        if request.method == "POST":
            email = request.POST.get("email")
            password = request.POST.get("password")

            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
                user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    messages.success(request, "You are logged in")
                    return redirect("jew_app:home")
                else:
                    messages.warning(request, "User Does Not Exist. Create an account")

            except:
                messages.warning(request, f"User with {email} does not exist")

        context = {

        }

        return render(request, 'user/login.html', context)
```

models.py

```
    class User(AbstractUser):
        email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False)
        username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
        mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)


        USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

        def __str__(self):
            return self.username
```

I tried Django built-in form etc. I was able to create the superuser and the superuser details are stored in database but the users after registering the superuser through form fields are not getting stored in database.

Comment: Show us your forms in template.

Answer (score 1):

**Don’t use `form.is_valid()`, `form.save()`, or any custom register form like `UserRegisterForm`**.

Instead, in your `register()` view you must create an User entry with `create_user()`. Follow the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#creating-users):

```python
username = request.POST.get("username")

# Manage username conflict here...

User.objects.create_user(username, request.POST.get("email"), request.POST.get("password"))
messages.success(request, f"hey {username}, account created successfully")
user = authenticate(...)
if user is not None:
    # Do something with the authenticated user...
else:
    # Do something in case of error...
```

Also you must manage any username conflict. If two users have the same email address, you must for example refuse the registration.

Comment: I tried it but, it doesn't make any changes will I have to provide my forms.py. While entering in registration fields, in the terminal it shows success

Comment: I edited the answer so you can try again.

Answer (score 0):

**[Reuse Django’s `UserCreationForm`.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms)**

Follow the documentation about [Substituting a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Then your registration form may looks like:

```python
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "password1", "password2", "email",)

    # Some customization…
```

Also, you’ll have to write your own user manager, so something like :

```python
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```